# ¿Cómo podría redireccionar a alguien en base si tiene activa una cookie?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

¡Holaaa!

Me gustaría saber si es posible causar una redirección a alguien a través de una cookie previamente establecida. Estoy usando php para crear la cookie y la condición (en caso de que posea tal cookie) pero lo que pasa es que redirecciona sea cual sea el resultado de si tiene la cookie o no. Lo que me gustaría hacer es un one-time view, es decir, que los usuarios entren a una parte de mi web por una vez y que no puedan volver a acceder. En caso de que no se pueda a través de cookies, ¿cómo podría hacerlo?
Gracias

ACTUALIZACIÓN: Respeto a lo que ha dicho Mateo, he hecho los cambios pertinentes y aún así sigue pasando lo mismo. Dejo aquí el código actualizado.

```
<?php
if( isset( $_COOKIE['Supremassy']) )
{
header("Location: https://google.es");
}

else
{

setcookie("Supremassy", 1, time() + (60*2) );
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿De casualidad será porque estás estableciendo un valor con `setcookie` en todo momento? No sé mucho de php.

Comment: @Mateo ¡Ay va! Es cierto, revisando algo mejor el código es básicamente un bucle, así normal que siempre me redirija a google. Gracias

Comment: tu cookie expira en 2 minutos  es  ese el comportaminto que pretendes???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código se puede simplificar.

En primer lugar, tú puedes asignar la cookie sin más, no es necesario darle un valor `true` o `false` que sólo crea confusión aquí. Haciéndolo así, sólo verificas si la cookie está establecida o no.

Otra cosa es que puedes comprobar los valores booleanos sin más con `if (valorBooleano)` sin tener que hacer el verboso y redundante: `if(valorBooleano==true)`.

Creo que así el código es menos confuso:

```
function comprobarCookies()
{
    return isset($_COOKIE['Supremassy']);
}
        // ---------------
if( comprobarCookies() ) {
    #La cookie existe, redirigimos
    header("Location: https://google.es");
} else {
    #La cookie no existe, la creamos.
    #Conviene indicar el tiempo de duración de la misma (horas, días...)
    setcookie("Supremassy", "");
}
```

Si en `comprobarCookies()` no piensas hacer nada más, con esto bastaría, tampoco hay que crear funciones por crear:

```
if( isset($_COOKIE['Supremassy']) ) {
    #La cookie existe, redirigimos
    header("Location: https://google.es");
} else {
    #La cookie no existe, la creamos.
    #Conviene indicar el tiempo de duración de la misma (horas, días...)
    setcookie("Supremassy", "");
}
```

Comment: el problema es que aún así entrando en incógnito y demás, me sigue redireccionando a google, sin antes haber puesto la cookie

Comment: @galaixagalicia no etiendo tu comentario. Con el código implementado te redireccionará a google cuando la cookie no exista únicamente. ¿No es eso lo que quieres? Además, conviene especificar por cuánto tiempo quieres que la cookie exista.

Comment: no, no, al revés, que redireccionen a los usuarios que tienen la cookie establecida y que a los usuarios que no la tenga se le cree.

Comment: @galaixagalicia Pues al leer esto: *Lo que me gustaría hacer es un one-time view, es decir, que los usuarios entren a una parte de mi web por una vez y que no puedan volver a acceder.* ... se entiende justo lo contrario de lo que acabas de decir. Ahora edito la respuesta.

Comment: @galaixagalicia revisa la respuesta editada. En la pregunta no aparece si debería ocurrir algo más cuando la cookie no exista, aparte de crearla.

Comment: @A.Cedano me parece que la cookies no debería de crearse a la ligera, debido a que existe una legislación al rededor dl asunto; en ese caso lo que se puede hacer es validar si el usuario esta de acuerdo en que esta cookies se cree y se utilicé, me parece a mi ... puedo estar equivocado ...

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent se supone que al entrar al sitio se le preguntó al usuario si aceptaba Cookies y ya partiendo de su aceptación podrías crear Cookies sin tener que preguntar de nuevo si las acepta. Si te das cuenta, ya en la mayoría de los sitios cuando entras te hacen esa pregunta una vez, no `N` veces, aunque durante la navegación se creen `N` Cookies como podría ocurrir.